# How to use devise user_signed_in? with if-else condition in react-rails jsx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, reactjs

I am trying to implement devise user_signed_in? in jsx file with if-else condition i.e if user logged-in show "logout" else if logged-out show "login". Seems like I'm unable to implement it correctly. Please correct me out.

**header.html.erb**

```
<%= react_component("headerBar", {userSignedIn: user_signed_in?}, {prerender:true}) %>
```

**header.js.jsx**

```
var headerBar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          if(this.props.userSignedIn) {
          <li><a href="/login"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  Sign Up</a></li>
          } else {
          <li><a href="/logout"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  Sign Out</a></li>
          }
          <li><a href="/join"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>  Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

declare a variable before the return statement, like this:

```
var userIcon = this.props.userSignedIn ? 
<li><a href="/login"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  Sign Up</a></li> :
<li><a href="/logout"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  Sign Out</a></li>;

return (
  <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    {userIcon}
  </ul>
);
```

more info here: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html